# Tegra X1 bootrom exploit portability potential (K1 in nexus 9 specifically)

Tags: exploit, android, exploit-development

I have been wondering if anyone here reckons  that porting the recent Tegra X1 bootrom exploit is achievable? The code in question does not seem likely to be going through significant changes frequently and it got me hoping  that I would one day get to run EL3 code on it. Another thing is that I am not sure about is how to force this tablet in APX mode without actually rendering bootlooder-related partitions unusable first...

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that the K1 is vulnerable? I did a quick search and all that I found was that "NVIDIA Tegra X2, which was launched in 2016, and later Tegra systems on a chip (SOCs) such as Xavier, are not affected by this issue." from the official [Nvidia security notice](https://nvidia.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/4660/~/security-notice%3A-nvidia-tegra-rcm-vulnerability), but no explicit confirmations. Assuming it is, let's move on.

On [fail0verflow's write-up of their Tegra RCM exploit ShofEL2 and how to use it on the Nintendo Switch](https://fail0verflow.com/blog/2018/shofel2/), they said that the preferable method of putting the switch into RCM mode is by pressing Volume-Up, power, and the 'home button' all at once (the other methods being messing-up the bootloader/physically removing the flash and rebooting into RCM from software). They said that the home button wasn't the home button on the Joy-Con, but rather the 10<sup>th</sup> pin on the right Joy-Con connector (that pin and ground are where it would be connected if it were a button, anyway). [According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tegra) (and fail0verflow in the blog post I linked earlier), the majority of Tegra devices run Android. As such, I would believe that this 10<sup>th</sup> pin is connected to the same CPU GPIO pin that the home pin on a Tegra-powered Android is connected to. So try that, turn your tablet off and press the power button while holding the home button at the bottom and volume-up. If it appears to still be off, plug it into your computer. When my I plug my Switch into my Linux system while it's in RCM mode, the `lsusb` command lists it as 'NVIDIA Corp.' (It is listed as 'Nintendo, Co. Ltd.' when the Switch is normally booted into the Switch operating system.) If you use Windows, try checking Device Manager. You can use that to verify that you got your tablet into RCM mode.

This applies to anything, not just Tegras: even if pieces of code share a vulnerability, the slightest differences can cause an exploit written for one to not work for the other (this is especially true for low-level stuff like a BootROM). On the other hand, in the [readme](https://github.com/fail0verflow/shofel2/blob/master/README.md) file in fail0verflow's ShofEL2 repository, they said that the exploit 'probably works on the Ouya', which is an Android device with the Tegra 3 (and the Tegra K1 is probably more similiar to the X1 than the Tegra 3 is to the X1).

I don't know if you have a payload in mind; if not, you can probably use an existing kernel image built for the device. (Even if you don't in the end, it can be helpful to make sure that the exploit worked before investing your time in building your own kernel.) The following only applies if you do use an Android kernel image: If you use the exploit to boot the default kernel with the default cmdline, it will (probably) boot-up normally. To make sure the exploit worked try passing an invalid `init=` parameter or something else to cause it to panic. (I don't know if Android kernels are usually compiled with `CONFIG_VT=y`, and if not you won't see a panic message. If not, try running a simple executable that creates a file on an SD card, for example.)

Let me know what results you have, I'm also interested in porting this exploit. (I only own a Switch, but I've been contemplating purchasing a Tegra 3-powered Microsoft Surface RT and trying the exploit on that. The Surface RT uses UEFI Secure Boot to ensure that the end-user only uses Windows RT.)

I find it really funny that this vulnerability has supposedly been around for a really long time (at least since the launch of the X1) and no one noticed it until the Switch (and when they did, three separate groups discovered it around the same time).